# List View dont Show values

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view and I want to show some values inside it, the connection is made without any error, but my list view doesn't show those values, I don't know what I did wrong, my code is below please help me. I think I have done some wrong in the customeadapter.. please check my custom adapter CustomAdapterViewDriver.

My Activity

```
public class PerformBargain extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView UserDetails;
JSONArray jsonArray;
SendPostRequest mSendPostRequest;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perform_bargain);
    UserDetails=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.UserDetails);
    mSendPostRequest= new SendPostRequest();
    mSendPostRequest.execute();



}

class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
   {

   String postData = "";

   HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= null;
   @Override
   protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {

       try {
           Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
           String id=bundle.getString("ID");



           httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://192.168.0.14:8080/GoodsServer/ViewRideDetails.jsp").openConnection();
           httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
           httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

           DataOutputStream outputStream= new 
           DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
           outputStream.writeBytes("id=" +id);
           outputStream.flush();
           outputStream.close();

           InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
           InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

           int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
           while (inputStreamData != -1) {
               char currentData = (char) inputStreamData;
               inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
               postData += currentData;
           }
          jsonArray=new JSONArray(postData.trim());
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           if (httpURLConnection!= null) {
               httpURLConnection.disconnect();
           }
       }

       return jsonArray;




   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),postData,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       try{
               CustomAdapterViewDriver customAdapterViewDriver=new CustomAdapterViewDriver(PerformBargain.this,s);
               UserDetails.setAdapter(customAdapterViewDriver);

   }catch (Exception e)
       {

           System.out.print(e);
       }}


   }
```

CustomAdapterViewDriver Class

```
class CustomAdapterViewDriver extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

String ids;
TextView name,email,phone,Source,destination;
private final Activity activity;
private final JSONArray jsonArray;

public CustomAdapterViewDriver(Activity activity, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    assert activity != null;
    assert jsonArray != null;

    this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    this.activity = activity;
}


@Override public int getCount() {

    return jsonArray.length();
}

@Override public JSONObject getItem(int position) {

    return jsonArray.optJSONObject(position);
}

@Override public long getItemId(int position) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = getItem(position);

    return jsonObject.optLong("id");
}

@Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null)
        view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.userviewforbargain, null);
    JSONObject jsonObject = getItem(position);
    name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.namevu);
    phone =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    email=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.email);
    Source=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sourceadderss);
    destination=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.destinationaddress);

    try{

        name.setText(jsonObject.getString("Name"));
        phone.setText(jsonObject.getString("Phone"));
        email.setText(jsonObject.getString("Email"));
        Source.setText(jsonObject.getString("Source"));
        destination.setText(jsonObject.getString("DestAdd"));
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

        System.out.print(e);

    }
    return view;


}
```

}

userviewforbargain Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

     android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="#000"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Phone"

    android:textColor="#000"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Email"

    android:textColor="#000"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="SourceAdderss"

    android:textColor="#000"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Destination"

    android:textColor="#000"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/namevu"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="sourceadderss"
        android:id="@+id/sourceadderss"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Destination"
        android:id="@+id/destinationaddress"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with my XML file... I just add a relative layout to my XML and its working fine now.

code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.user.good_carriermacfast.PerformBargain"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="110dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

     android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="#000"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Phone"

    android:textColor="#000"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Email"

    android:textColor="#000"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="SourceAdderss"

    android:textColor="#000"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Destination"

    android:textColor="#000"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/namevu"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="sourceadderss"
        android:id="@+id/sourceadderss"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Destination"
        android:id="@+id/destinationaddress"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that it was more to do with the fact that your original was a LinearLayout with wrap_content, while the view below is match_parent.

You didn't just change the top layout, you changed your next LinearLayout to layout_width="110dp"